# Hausdorff topologies on Q

Tags: topological-groups

Is there any description known of the Hausdorff topologies on $\mathbb{Q}$ compatible with the group operations?

Comment: There are $2^{2^{Card(\mathbb{Q})}}$ distinct *field* topologies on $\mathbb{Q}$, not so much describable. See http://mathoverflow.net/q/106448/6451 . See also Zelenyuk, Protasov, Topologies on abelian groups, Mathematics of the USSR-Izvestiya(1991),37(2):445